# Updated feature not deploying NEW web parts when using powershell

Tags: feature-upgrade

I have added a new web part to a feature of existing web parts in a wsp solution. If I manually go to a site collection and deactivate and reactivate the feature via site collection features, the new web part is available in the gallery and can be added onto a page.

I am upgrading this solution across many site collections using powershell.
My powershell script loops through the site collections. If it finds the updated feature it deactivates the feature using Disable-SPFeature ...and then I run Enable-SPFeature bla bla to activate it again.

I have stepped through and run the powershell manually and can see the feature activated and deactivated and reactivated again if I refresh the browser and then run each command but the new web part does not get added to the gallery this way.

Can anyone shed any light on why the new .webpart file doesn't get added via the powershell method?

Here is a sample of the powershell where I do the work:

First after upgrading the solution I run this to force the xml to the file system.

Install-SPFeature -Path "Intranet.WebParts_Site-WebParts" -Force

```
foreach ($site in $webApp.Sites)
{       
        if ($site.Features[$myportalWebPartsFeatureId] -ne $null)
        {
            Write-host "Disabling Web Parts feature" -ForegroundColor Cyan              
            Disable-SPFeature "Intranet.WebParts_Site-WebParts" -Url $site.Url -confirm:$false
            Write-host "Enabling Web Parts feature" -ForegroundColor Cyan               
            Enable-SPFeature "Intranet.WebParts_Site-WebParts" -Url $site.Url -confirm:$false
        }
```

Comment: What is the full version number (or Cumulative Update) of your installation?

Comment: Can you share feature activation code? Does it work manually using GUI feature activation?

Comment: No feature activation code used. Works perfectly using GUI activation.
Version: SharePoint Server 14.0.6029.1000 + hotfix 14.0.6106.5002 for portal

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same problem. I used the **Install-SPFeature** command after **Disable-SPFeature** and it worked for me.

```
Write-host "Disabling Web Parts feature" -ForegroundColor Cyan              
Disable-SPFeature "Intranet.WebParts_Site-WebParts" -Url $site.Url -confirm:$false

Install-SPFeature "Intranet.WebParts_Site-WebParts" -Force


Write-host "Enabling Web Parts feature" -ForegroundColor Cyan               
Enable-SPFeature "Intranet.WebParts_Site-WebParts" -Url $site.Url -confirm:$false
```